# What is a different way to say "I choose this because..."

Tags: word-choice, syntax, synonyms

I am writing supplementary applications for universities and they are asking for extracurricular activities I have done as well as a description for each.  In the description, I am talking about why I decided to join or participate in the activity.  I would like to highlight the fact that the decision to join the activities was **my choice** and not anyone else pressuring me.  The problem is that "I chose this club because..." I becoming overused.  Is there another way I can phrase it?

Comment: *What made me to get into this..*; *The reason I got into it is/was....* and there could be many.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways to do this. Rearranging the words to make it less obvious such as:

> I participate in [activity] this was my choice because [reason(s)]
>
> I also enjoy [activity] and [reason(s)] is/are why I do it

another way would be to eliminate the 'i chose this because' part, such as:

> One activity I am a part of is [activity]. [reason(s)] made me think it would be a good choice for me.

example:

> I am a part of many extracurricular activities, including but not limited to Swim Team, Boy Scouts of America, and Church small group. I entered BSA(Boy Scouts of America) because I am a hard worker and thought it would be fun to go camping every month. My troop has a high level of control by the scouts, while the adult leaders don't do very much. I like this high level of control because I get to make more decisions, such as what we will eat at the next camp-out, or where we will go. I earned my Eagle award last year, and had a blast doing so. Thank you for taking the time to read this and I hope you will consider me.
> from: Steve Lastname

although, that might not be the same level of professionalism you're looking for.